# What's a clean way to stop mongod on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mongodb, launchd

i'm running mongo 1.8.2 and trying to see how to cleanly shut it down on Mac.

on our ubuntu servers i can shutdown mongo cleanly from the mongo shell with:

```
> use admin
> db.shutdownServer()
```

but on my Mac, it does not kill the mongod process.  the output shows that it 'should be' shutdown but when i ps -ef | grep mongo it shows me an active process.  also, i can still open a mongo shell and query my dbs like it was never shutdown.

the output from my db.shutdownServer() locally is:

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.2
connecting to: test
> use admin                  
switched to db admin
> db.shutdownServer()
Tue Dec 13 11:44:21 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Tue Dec 13 11:44:21 query failed : admin.$cmd { shutdown: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1
server should be down...
Tue Dec 13 11:44:21 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1
Tue Dec 13 11:44:21 reconnect 127.0.0.1 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1
Tue Dec 13 11:44:21 Error: error doing query: unknown shell/collection.js:150
```

i know i can just kill the process but i'd like to do it more cleanly.

Comment: How have you started `mongod`? Just at the shell? Using `launchctl`?

Comment: Do you have any information from the logs? It could be that MongoDB is "auto-restarting". You may want to run with `--logappend`, though a brand new log file is a clear indication that the process restarted.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

It's probably because launchctl is managing your mongod instance. If you want to start and shutdown mongod instance, unload that first:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

Then start mongod manually:

```
mongod -f path/to/mongod.conf --fork
```

You can find your mongod.conf location from `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist`.

After that, `db.shutdownServer()` would work just fine.

Added Feb 22 2014:

If you have mongodb installed via homebrew, homebrew actually has a handy `brew services` command. To show current running services:

`brew services list`

To start mongodb:

`brew services start mongodb-community`

To stop mongodb if it's already running:

`brew services stop mongodb-community`

**Update***

As edufinn pointed out in the comment, `brew services` is now available as user-defined command and can be installed with following command: `brew tap gapple/services`.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, currently, if you have mongodb installed via homebrew you would actually need to do `launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.mongodb` to stop mongodb.

Comment: As Sep. 2014, there is a deprecation notice in `brew` regarding `brew services`: `$ brew services
Warning: brew services is unsupported and will be removed soon.`

Comment: As Dec. 2014, `brew services` has been removed. `$ brew services Error: Unknown command: services`

Comment: `brew services` is now available as user-defined command and can be installed with following command: `brew tap gapple/services`.

Comment: I can get `brew services` with `brew tap gapple/services`, but after `brew services start mongodb` I see `...==> Successfully started `mongodb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb)` while in fact the process isn't running (as verified by trying to do something on the db), and `brew services list` gives me `Warning: No user-space services controlled by `brew services` running...`. The `launchctl` suggestions below aren't working for me either. So these techniques unfortunately don't work any more.

Comment: @James  brew service start/stop command is just so clean and brilliant.. Thank you

Comment: After I start the mongodb service, my node server is unable to connect to it. However if I start the mongodb from command line, it works fine. I guess it must be port issue.. How to set the port when starting the service ?

Comment: FYI I installed MongDB recently on my Mac OS and could not find based on name `mongodb`. I had to install via `brew install mongodb-community`. Not sure what the story is behind this, maybe they renamed it or something.

```$ brew search mongodb
==> Formulae
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community ✔               mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@3.4
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community-shell           mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@3.6
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@3.2             mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.0

...```

Then I could start/stop via `brew services start/stop mongodb-community`

Comment: The start command is wrong in the post. It should be `brew services start mongodb-community` not `stop`

Answer (score 48):

If you installed mongodb with homebrew, there's an easier way:

List mongo job with launchctl:

```
launchctl list | grep mongo
```

Stop mongo job:

```
launchctl stop <job label>
```

(For me this is `launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.mongodb`)

Start mongo job:

```
launchctl start <job label>
```

Answer (score 28):

Simple way is to get the process id of mongodb and kill it.
Please note DO NOT  USE kill -9 pid for this as it may cause damage to the database.

so,
1. get the pid of mongodb

$ pgrep mongo

you will get pid of mongo, Now

$ kill

You may use kill -15  as well

Answer (score 26):

If you have installed mongodb community server via homebrew, then you can do:

```
brew services list
```

This will list the current services as below:

```
Name              Status  User          Plist
mongodb-community started <your_user_name> /Users/<your_user_name>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

redis             stopped
```

Then you can restart mongodb by first stopping and restart:

```
brew services stop mongodb
brew services start mongodb
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to stop the MongoDB server using the `port` command itself.

```
sudo port unload mongodb
```

And to start it again.

```
sudo port load mongodb
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out these docs:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-SendingaUnixINTorTERMsignal

If you started it in a terminal you should be ok with a `ctrl + 'c'` -- this will do a clean shutdown.

However, if you are using launchctl there are specific instructions for that which will vary depending on how it was installed.

If you are using Homebrew it would be `launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.mongodb`

Answer (score 3):

The solutions provided by others used to work for me but is not working for me anymore, which is as below.

```
brew services stop mongodb
brew services start mongodb
```

`brew services list` gives

```
Name              Status  User      Plist
mongodb-community started XXXXXXXXX /Users/XXXXXXXXX/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

So I used `mongodb-community` instead of `mongodb` which worked for me

```
brew services stop mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but its one I found while searching as well.

If you installed with `brew` then the solution would actually be the this:

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`

Answer (score 0):

If the service is running via brew, you can stop it using the following command:

```
brew services stop mongodb
```