# Can I just kill mongod to stop mongo?

Tags: macos, mongodb, administration

I am very new at Mongo. I am running `mongod` as described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/) in `Mac OS X`. I am running two `mongod` processes from the command line. If I need to stop the `mongod` processes I just execute `kill <pid of mongod>`. Is it the recommended way to stop `mongod`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is quite late, but I had same problem now, and I found one easy way :

```
Esan-iMac:~$mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: admin
2015-02-19T10:54:22.574+0200 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
```

It's giving some odd messages, but it works.

And I made **alias**-command for running it easy.

```
alias stop-mongo='/opt/mongo/release/bin/mongo admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"'
```

This works at least if you start your mongo manually (e.g. with --fork option).

Answer (score 59):

It finally succeeded (Ubuntu 15.04) with

//1.find process by name:

```
$ pgrep mongo
```

1350

//2.kill mongod-process

```
$ kill 1350
```

Comment: I had to prefix the kill statement with `sudo`. I'm on macOS Catalina

Comment: `killall mongod` will also works (only if you don't want to kill a specific instance)

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer by Esa is correct. Also, regarding whether using kill is recommended - yes, but with flag `-2` or no flag, never use `-9`. As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes).

```
kill -2 `pgrep mongo`
```

**Alias**

```
alias stopmongo='kill -2 `pgrep mongo`'
```

Comment: can u explain y we need to use -2 flag

Comment: @SujayUN - Please check the link to official docs of mongo in the answer. This is recommended by mongo developers. The reason I mentioned not to use -9, was AFAIK(not perfect) it's a kill signal and kills the application instantaneously. -2 in layman terms is a Soft Interrupt, which tells mongo to finish its critical task, don't accept any future data R/W requests and exit. This prevents data corruption. For further reading on Signals, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_01.html

Comment: Something you have to use -9 when -2 won't work, in a worst case scenario

Answer (score 5):

**Windows**

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

For systems with auth enabled, users may only issue db.shutdownServer() when authenticated to the admin database or via the localhost interface on systems without authentication enabled.

**Linux**

```
mongod --shutdown
```

you can also use

```
kill <mongod process ID>
```

see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: Thanks. Added that I am running `Mongo` in Mac. It is interesting `mongod` does not have `shutdown` option in Mac :((

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495293/whats-a-clean-way-to-stop-mongod-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 4):

For year of 2020:

Mongo should be installed through Brew, rather than the old school style on linux: i.e. tar.gz package download/uncompress/configure/run.

In the brew way, if Mongo is installed by `brew tap mongodb/brew` and `brew install mongodb-community`, you could do as follows to stop (and disable) it alike Systemd on Linux.

```
~ brew services list
Name              Status  User     Plist
mongodb-community started zhengxin /Users/zhengxin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

~ brew services stop mongodb-community
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer!
I am on a mac and it helped me a lot!

Comment: (Edit: I know the answer refers to the Mac install, but just adding about the official way of installing it on Linux:) today MongoDB Community Edition is available from its own dedicated repositories in many distros, that's the "official" way of installing it on Linux [according to the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/).

Answer (score 2):

terminal$ kill $(pgrep mongod)

Answer (score 2):

this command can help killing the mongod process. `sudo pkill -f mongod`

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered an issue with "just killing the mongod" in mac...

1. The mongod is kept running as a service by "launchctl" in mac systems.  "just killing" it will kill that service.
2. Now to use mongo shell we do mongod again, however for other development purpose like connecting from node we need to make sure to run mongod time and again.
3. Other alternative is shut down the system and start again.

Better Way :

Start using launchctl to manage such services. Here is an example for that :

[What is the correct way to start a mongod service on linux / OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596521/what-is-the-correct-way-to-start-a-mongod-service-on-linux-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is `Ctrl + C`, which worked for me on a blocking bash shell under El Capitan.

Comment: the thing is that it's running in the background, and the terminal is not availble

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured autostart, killing the process won't help, new one will start immediately. In order to disable autostart, you have to locate the autostart file first. You can try to find the file using e.g.

`find / -name "mongodb.plist"` or `locate "mongodb.plist"`

After the file is found, remove the autostart config using (you can try without `sudo` first, it's not needed if you have done the installation using Homebrew):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w <file>
```

If you want to kill the process anyway and it's not using autostart, remember not to use `kill -9 <PID>`, it can damage the db. `kill -1 <PID>` or `kill -15 <PID>` should be safe options.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

official guide

remember not to use kill -9

otherwise maybe you need to remove lock file in dbpath

Comment: It is very helpful to link to the docu. In addition I would also add a short direct answer to the question, like "Yes: kill <pid> is one of the recommended ways to stop the process".

Comment: This answer is fine, but almost identical to the answer from saurabheights. In the future please check existing answers first to avoid duplication.