# stop or kill mongodb server from running

Tags: mongodb

I have an auto start mongodb on startup on my mac os. Mongo is starting on start up.
I try to kill or stop mongodb server(local server on my machine) but nothing is working.

After running:  `ps aux | grep mongo`

I'll get

```
root  65  0.1  0.7  3570824 115476 ??  Ss 6:27PM  0:01.37 /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod
myname 454  0.0  0.0  2432772    656 s000  S+    6:37PM   0:00.00 grep mongo
```

I tried with `kill 65` and even `kill -9` which is not good at all.

 But still mongo is up and running.
I can't kill the processes I can't stop the processes.

How do I do?  Any body can help? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried solution listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495293/whats-a-clean-way-to-stop-mongod-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: Yes, but with no result. Still can't stop the process. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What commands are you trying? What are their outputs?

Comment: As you can see I used kill ... and even
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist. Are there more command which can help?