# MongoDB connect with credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I've been using MongoDB for a little while now. I've always managed to connect without using a username and password (on 2 servers I setup Mongo on).

I now want to change this so username and password has to be used. So far, I created a user in the admin database with the userAdminAnyDatabase role. I can see the user is in there.

Next I try to make my connection and test it:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@localhost:8080/MEAN");

var conn = mongoose.connection;             

conn.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

I've not put in my real username and password there of course.
With this, I get the following error: `[Error: connection closed]`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: is your password "password" and your username "username"?

Comment: @HelioSantos Haha no, I've obviously not posted the real credentials for security reasons

Comment: start `mongo` instance usind `--auth` mode, or set `auth=true` in `mongo.conf`

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv thanks, where do I find the mongo.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect with credentials, start mongo `mongo` instance using `--auth`

```
sudo mongod --dbpath=/your/db/path --auth
```

**or**

in `/etc/mongodb.conf`, set

```
auth=true
```

Then restart service

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. On my local version of Mongo (Mac Yosemite) I don't seem to have the mongodb.conf file in the /etc/ directory (although I can see it on another server I have it installed).

Comment: i mean whereever `mongo` configuration file :)

Comment: Ah yes I found it in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`. Thanks I'll try this now.

Comment: Trying to restart Mongo, I get this error: `sudo: service: command not found`

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: OSX Yosemite, Macbook

Comment: i dont knw how you run `mongod` in it.Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495293/whats-a-clean-way-to-stop-mongod-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Did you check `brew services list` if installed via `brew`

Comment: OK that helped. Now I'm editing mongod.conf. It currently looks like this: `systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1` Do I just add `auth=true` to the bottom?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71505/discussion-between-latheef-itzmeontv-and-coop).