# How to use `mongorestore` to restore a database using a TAR.GZ file

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, localhost, mongorestore

Simple question:

```
$ mongorestore --gzip ./Mongo_DB_dump/restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.tar.gz
2020-07-09T18:10:48.207-0500    Failed: file .\Mongo_DB_dump\restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.tar.gz does not have .bson extension
2020-07-09T18:10:48.209-0500    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

How can I restore a database using a ´tar.gz´ file if I don't know the name of the database?
I'm trying to import a dump from a production instance (MongoDB Cloud) into my local environment. I don't have any previous version of the database in my local if that's relevant.

### Edit

I also tried to use `mongostore --gzip` using the *.tar.gz* file and also I tried extracting the contents into a *.tar* file but, with both files I got the following error:

```
2020-07-09T22:33:07.127-0500    Failed: file .\Mongo_DB_dump\restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.tar.gz does not have .bson extension
2020-07-09T22:33:07.128-0500    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

I also tried using `/archive:<path-to-file>` unsuccessfully:

```
$ mongorestore --gzip /archive:./Mongo_DB_dump/restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.tar.gz
2020-07-09T22:52:59.076-0500    Failed: stream or file does not appear to be a mongodump archive
2020-07-09T22:52:59.077-0500    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

I even attempted to change blindlessly the `.tar` extension into `.bson` but that didn't worked out of course:

```
2020-07-09T22:08:24.175-0500    checking for collection data in Mongo_DB_dump\restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.bson
2020-07-09T22:08:24.601-0500    restoring Mongo_DB_dump.restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49 from Mongo_DB_dump\restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.bson
2020-07-09T22:08:24.664-0500    finished restoring Mongo_DB_dump.restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49 (0 documents, 0 failures)
2020-07-09T22:08:24.664-0500    Failed: Mongo_DB_dump.restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49: error restoring from Mongo_DB_dump\restore-8f05kcbfhfbce745735eff49.bson: reading bson input: invalid BSONSize: 1953719666 bytes
2020-07-09T22:08:24.664-0500    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: [mongorestore --gzip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/index.html#cmdoption-mongorestore-gzip) is used to restore from compressed files created by `mongodump --gzip`.

Comment: @prasad_ Hi, thanks for trying to help. I updated my question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just extracted the contents of the `.tar.gz` file to `C:\ProgramData\MongoDB\data\db` and overwrite everything there...
I'm not very convinced about this one, but at least I was able to work because this way I got the database, collections and documents visible to *Mongo Shell*.
Please share a better answer if you know it.

Answer (score 16):

Just in case someone else run into this problem:

I am currently using db version **v4.4.5** and restored the backup in 2 different ways:

1. If you already have a dumped archive file and compressed it **dump.tar.gz** , then you can just decompress/extract the archive file first and then restore it with command:

`mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017 --archive dump.tar`

2. Or else, you can directly restore the **dump.tar.gz** using command:

`mongorestore --host=localhost --port=27017 --gzip --archive=dump.tar.gz`

Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot.    btw, --archive is not needed if import files form mongodump.

Comment: For restore  `--gzip` is necessary, strangely...

Answer (score 0):

On Mac (Big Sur, Intel), I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827915/location-of-the-mongodb-database-on-mac) my MongoDB files in `/usr/local/var/mongodb`. I then **backed up** my current `mongodb` folder and then replaced its contents with the decompressed contents (individual files and folders) of the `.tar.gz` backup file.

I then [restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495293/whats-a-clean-way-to-stop-mongod-on-mac-os-x) my local MongoDB service.

This **replaces all of the current data you have locally** with the archived file's contents.

This answer is built on top of @Metafaniel's [OC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63065844/4927003).